# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, class, csv, tkinter, items

I am very new to python and have been trying to teach myself as I go (not the best method this deep into python but for time's sake I need too). The modules I've imported are Tkinter and csv. Let me know if you have any questions,

For the sake of brevity I am not going to post my entire code on here but I will include the entire error and indicate the line that the error is applying to. Everything that is below is in a class called MainApp.

```
def SubmitEdit(self):
    self.key=""
    self.val=""
    new_rows = []
    self.changes = {self.key:self.val}
    with open("info.csv",'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f):
        for row in reader:
            new_row = row
            for field in row:
                if field == "NAME":
                    print "groovy"
            for (self.key,self.val) in self.changes.items():
                new_row = [ x.replace(self.key,self.val) for x in new_row]
            new_rows.append(new_row)
     with open("info.csv","wb") as f:
         writer = csv.writer(f):
         writer.writerows(new_rows)
```

I wrote this code out separately to make sure it worked before putting it in the program and it worked perfectly, but when I put it in the class and made the changes (I thought) I needed to make to the lines of code / variables it didn't work. So that leads me to believe that I'm just correcting something incorrectly.

Here is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py",line 1536, in__call__
        return self.func(*args)
    File "C:\Python27\draft.py", line 328, in SubmitEdit
        for (self.key,self,val) in self.changes:
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Where line 328 refers to the line:
"or (self.key,self.val) in self.changes.items():"

I have changed around (I feel like) the presence or absence of "self." for all variables but I just can't get it to work.

EDIT:
I altered the code to look like this:

```
def SubmitEdit(self):
    new_rows = []
    self.changes = {"MTMA",123}
    with open("info.csv",'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f):
        for row in reader:
            new_row = row
            for field in row:
                if field == "NAME":
                    print "groovy"
            for (key,val) in self.changes.items():
                new_row = [ x.replace(key,val) for x in new_row]
            new_rows.append(new_row)
     with open("info.csv","wb") as f:
         writer = csv.writer(f):
         writer.writerows(new_rows)
```

as per the comments, but still get the exact same error.

Comment: Well the error itself is saying there is no attribute called `items()`. So try and remove `.items()` from `self.changes.items()` http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Also, why did you do `self.changes = {self.key:self.val}`? If you are just trying to reference a dictionary, adding `self.key:self.val` is not necessary as `self.changes = {}` is enough.

Comment: When I take away the .items() it returns a ValueError that says "need more than 0 values to unpack". I will try leaving the dictionary empty.

Comment: Yes, because you have nothing in your key and value. You initiated those variables with nothing.

Comment: Can you specify what you're passing into the function as `self`?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by that. (As explained above I'm pretty amateur), but when I don't include the "self." it will give me another error.

Comment: What are you doing to call the function?

Comment: The SubmitEdit function is called when a button in the class is pushed. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As you can see from the latest updated code -

```
self.changes = {"MTMA",123}
```

When you define self.changes as above , you are actually defining a set , not a dictionary , since you used ',' (comma) instead of colon , I am pretty sure in your actual code you are using comma itself , not colon .

To define a dictionary with "MTMA" as key and 123 as value , use a colon in between them , Example -

```
self.changes = {"MTMA":123}
```

Do similarly in your actual code as well.

If what you want is an empty dictionary , define it as -

```
self.changes = {}
```

Comment: This saved my life! I would have spent hours without seeing the typo!

Comment: Absolutely right!